# Data Splitting, Melting, and Transformation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, dataformat

I have the following code:

```
split_melt_and_transform_this_df = {'Concat' : [('AA,ABC,1,10,|','BB,ABC,,1,Z|','BB,ABC,,1,Z|''CC,ABC,50,,Z|'),('AA,ABC,1,10,|','BB,ABC,1,,Z|'),('AA,ABC,1,10,|','BB,ABC,1,,Z|'),('AA,ABC,5,,z|')], 'Item' : ['Backstreet Boys','NYSYNC', 'One Direction', 'Nirvana']}
split_melt_and_transform_this_df = pd.DataFrame(split_this_df)
split_melt_and_transform_this_df
```

I'd like to transform this 'Current DF' into the following 'Desired DF1' and 'Desired DF2' data frames:

[image]

DF2 is the especially tricky part.  All 'Z' values that end up in the final column need to be infinity.  If the row in the final column is blank, then show the value in the row of the adjacent column  (i.e., second to last column, where the '10' value shows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `explode` to get `df1`

```py
df1 = df.explode('Concat', ignore_index=True)
```

```
print(df1)

          Concat             Item
0  AA,ABC,1,10,|  Backstreet Boys
1   BB,ABC,,1,Z|  Backstreet Boys
2   BB,ABC,,1,Z|  Backstreet Boys
3  CC,ABC,50,,Z|  Backstreet Boys
4  AA,ABC,1,10,|           NYSYNC
5   BB,ABC,1,,Z|           NYSYNC
6  AA,ABC,1,10,|    One Direction
7   BB,ABC,1,,Z|    One Direction
8   AA,ABC,5,,Z|          Nirvana
```

To get `df2`, you can try to split the `Concat` column and convert list column to dataframe.

```py
df2 = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(df1.pop('Concat').str.split(',').tolist(), index=df1.index))
df2[4] = np.select([df2[4].eq('|'), df2[4].eq('Z|')], [df2[3], np.inf])
```

```
print(df2)

              Item   0    1   2   3    4
0  Backstreet Boys  AA  ABC   1  10   10
1  Backstreet Boys  BB  ABC       1  inf
2  Backstreet Boys  BB  ABC       1  inf
3  Backstreet Boys  CC  ABC  50      inf
4           NYSYNC  AA  ABC   1  10   10
5           NYSYNC  BB  ABC   1      inf
6    One Direction  AA  ABC   1  10   10
7    One Direction  BB  ABC   1      inf
8          Nirvana  AA  ABC   5      inf
```

Comment: How would I convert columns 2, 3, and 4 to be numeric or integers?

Comment: @HelpMeCode You can change the empty string to NaN then use astype to convert it to float.